# Sqlite3 Module in Python 3 Only Inserts 32767 Characters in a TEXT Field

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am inserting strings into a TEXT field on a table but they are truncated to just 32767 characters. How can I make the field virtually unlimited? I am using the sqlite3 module included in Python 3.

Comment: Can you run in `sqlite3` command line tool `.limit` and give us the output?

Comment: Works for me. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the responses, as @CL said it works. DB Browser for SQLite was truncating the text field but the data was there.